# How to keep emulator running even after we close terminal?

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, command-prompt

I launch the android emulator on my windows machine using the command line like

```
emulator -avd NEXUS_5_API_29
```

It runs without any error, but when I close the cmd window, the emulator also shuts down. How do I keep the emulator running even after I close command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Because running this way cause the terminal to create a thread to run the emulator. Closing the terminal means ending the thread too. To make the emulator run in the background add "start /min" before the command like so.

```
start /min emulator -avd NEXUS_5_API_29
```

This will still open a new terminal just for the emulator but its the closest to the unix command.

```
start emulator -avd NEXUS_5_API_29 &
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to run with a terminal in the background

Answer (score 0):

This answer works to at least run the emulator in the background of the shell, which makes that terminal tab usable for other commands.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67722546/11964247

```
nohup emulator @<emulator_name> &
```

example:

```
nohup emulator @Pixel_XL_API_31 &
```

Answer (score 0):

`screen emulator -avd NEXUS_5_API_29` will do the job