# Run AVD Emulator detached from terminal

Tags: android, linux, shell, android-emulator

Here is how we can run *AVD* directly from terminal

```
emulator -list-avds
emulator @Pixel_3a_API_30_x86
```

But I want it to be detached so that I can close my terminal and have the emulator still running. I tried to run something like this:

```
emulator -d @Pixel_3a_API_30_x86
```

But I got an error. Can someone tell how can we do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) command:

> Nohup, short for no hang up is a command in Linux systems that keep processes running even after exiting the shell or terminal.

```
nohup `emulator @Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 &`
```

here `&` puts the application into the background.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just had to remove the quotes to make it working

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively on Zsh.

```bash
emulator @Pixel_4_API_31 &|
```

https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html